# How to remove footer text from Blogger shopping template

Tags: css, templates, blogger

I want to create a shopping website with Blogger. I have downloaded a template 'Mega Shop' from http://www.bloggingnest.com/ecommerce-blogger-templates/.

I want to remove the footer text (image attached).
How can I do that?

[image: footer text image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: OP can you post the code snippet of that footer?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the html of the footer or simple way is to just make the display: none, for the footer element.